# Website Preloader - SVG Animated Icon Problem

Tags: javascript, php, svg

I'm trying to create a website preloader on WordPress CMS. In the PHP theme, I allow to change the Icon and Icon Color. Everything works fine but with one thing I don't know what to do. SVG icon doesn't animate immediately, but after page load. How to fix it?

SVG amimate immediately only when I use:
`<img src="'. $icon_url .'">` or `<object type="image/svg+xml" data="'. $icon_url .'"></object>` but in these cases I can't use `<?php $icon_color; ?>` to change the color of the icon.

Here is a pen where I want to change the fill color of the icon.

https://codepen.io/avigodesign/pen/GRpMOBJ

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As my practice, `<animateTransform>` doesn't work onload. Maybe there is any way for force to work, but I don't know about it. 
I share you my way:
I use css animation for it:
I add `rotate` animation:

```
@keyframes rotate {
   100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Combining `rotate` animation with svg element (id is`L9`) and delete `animateTransform`

```
#L9 {animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;}
```

So summary https://codepen.io/space-coding/pen/xxwBxOE
Of course, if you want better performance, you can delete this element after fadeOut animation because also if hide this svg, it keeping to rotate and use your GPU and RAM.

Comment: @Avigo, Let me know, if it helps?